# How to run my code in external window (terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want my python code to be run in external terminal (window).

Obviously i have to edit 'launch.json' file, where I should
change the option 'console:internalConsole' to 'console:externalTerminal'.
Problem is, I don't find a 'launch.json' file. I guess I have
to set up one, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Seems that the extension 'code runner' could do this trick,
but the extension breaks down.

I tried to make changes in the settings menu, I chose code to be run
in external terminal, but it still uses the internal one.

May be you can give me a direction ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's done.Created launch.json file and 'console: externalTerminal'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).